# Sorting data in Google DataFlow produced by a fixed time window?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm investigating Google Dataflow for a use case and I wonder if it's possible to sort data produced as an outcome of a fixed time window in a subsequent step? If so should I extend from an existing [core transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/transforms) or roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Cloud Dataflow, the elements in a window of a `PCollection` do not have a defined order, but many use cases for sorting can be addressed in other ways. For example, you can retrieve the "top *n* elements" via the `Combine`-based library transform [`Top`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Top). If your data has small per-window cardinality, then it may be feasible for you to read the elements in a window as a [side input](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs) and sort them or otherwise accomplish your goal.

I'd love to know more about your use case so I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm thinking of is to get events from various sources into Dataflow and aggregate them in a time window. When the time window is passed I'd like to sort all events on their timestamp order and then persist them to somewhere (probably file(s) on cloud storage).

Comment: Johan, can you provide some more details about what you want to do? Do you have many different keys and you want to separately sort the data for each key, or did you want a global sort. I assume you want to write out to multiple files? What volumes of data are you talking about?

Comment: @ReuvenLax I'd like to do a global sort of all our business event based on their timestamp per daily basis (or some feasible time unit) and then store them on google cloud storage. By doing this I'd like to later be able to replay them in the order they were created. Currently we have about 20 messages per second but it will increase (gradually).

Comment: In a streaming pipeline, to persist a file-based archive of messages for replay in sorted order as you describe, there are two options I would consider: (1) the side input approach I mentioned: use a fixed windowing small enough that all of the elements for a window will fit in memory and sor the iterables coming out of GBK. (2) use triggers to approximately chunk your input via AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(...). Note that this only sets a lower bound, and only on non-final panes.